# How do I echo the changes to a file in a sublime text plugin

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I am experimenting with a sublime text plugin and I'd like to capture every keystroke and print the inserted/deleted characters in the console along with the line number and position in the line.

There is an on_modified event in the event listener class that I can wire up but it returns a *view* object. I would like just the change that was made along with some info about the change (line and column number). I have extended other editors in the past and this info was available as a group of edits.

Is the inserted or deleted text along with a position in the file available from the event listener in a sublime plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid using the console.   Panels are very limited compared to views, and you'd be competing with the standard console output.   If you really want to use a panel, use [`create_output_panel & show_input_panel`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window)

I'd go with a stored string or stringarray that you continuously append the info to, and also create a command to print that stored info to a new view whenever you need it.   You could implement a dictionary to store change info per file.

You can use [`substr` & `rowcol`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) to find the most recently entered character, along with it's position.

---

---

#### Example:

[image: Demo]

#### Code:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class EventListener ( sublime_plugin.EventListener ):

    def on_modified ( self, view ):

        selectedRegions = view.sel()

        for region in selectedRegions:

            row, column = view.rowcol ( region.a )
            line = row + 1
            lastCharacter_Region = sublime.Region ( region.a - 1, region.a )
            lastCharacter = view.substr ( lastCharacter_Region )

            print ( "line: " + str ( line ) + "   col: " + str ( column ) + "   char: " + lastCharacter )
```

---

---

#### Notes:

**[1]**

I did not implement an output panel in the example above, for the sake of keeping it simple.   You can use the code as is, but if you're planning to release your plugin I would avoid using the console.

For example: I have the commands `sublime.log_input ( True )` & `sublime.log_commands ( True )` enabled by default *( for development purposes )*, so any system prints will be interspersed with all of the log output.

**[2]**

I'm working on a somewhat related plugin, **[LineDiff](https://github.com/Enteleform/ST_LineDiff)**.   The solutions I mentioned above will work great for keyboard-entered changes, but keeping track of programmatic changes is a bit more involved.  See **[this thread](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/highlight-changed-rows/18439/7)** for some of my thoughts & proposed solutions to that issue.

**[3]**

OP created a thread to further discuss this @ the SublimeText forum.

Significant progress has been made, check it out @:

## [**Retrieving inserted and deleted text**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/retrieving-inserted-and-deleted-text/18697)

Comment: > You can use substr & rowcol to find the most recently entered character, along with it's position.


This is what I am having trouble figuring out... can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Thanks for the info... looking at the api I would never have guessed this is how it works. Can I ask where you learned more about this API? I am new to sublime plugin development and want to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @MarkM : Here's a __[list of resources](https://github.com/Enteleform/Presentations/tree/master/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Sublime%20Text%20Plugins/2016-02-04#resource-links)__ I compiled which contains pretty much everything you need to know to build a solid foundation.

Comment: I hate to keep bothering you but I also would like to capture cuts and pastes of multiple characters at a time. The approach above works by grabbing the last character from the changed region (region.a -1 to region.a). 

It appears that region a and b are the same and are always empty (with a size of 0) so I can't tell how many new characters have been inserted or deleted. I have looked at the docs and can't seem to figure out if it is possible to retrieve that.